# How can I know the error in command in an exec function?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am using a ffmpeg command to cut a video with exec function in php. But it is not creating a video file and doesn't show any errors. I used exec as below

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:30.0 -t 00:00:10.0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 output.flv");
```

Can I get any help to know what is the error happening here?

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:30.0 -t 00:00:10.0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 output.flv",$output);
```

I tried it also. But I didn't get any error message in variable `$output`

Comment: Very similar, voting as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143006/php-execsvn-commit-is-not-returning-any-errors-nor-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, you first need to check the return value: non-zero values indicate there has been an error (given that the author of the program you are running adheres to the standard). This value is captured in [exec()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)'s third argument.

In second place, many programs do not send error messages to the standard output. Instead, they use the standard error. In this case, it seems safe to just [redirect](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) the latter to the former:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:30.0 -t 00:00:10.0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 output.flv 2>&1", $output, $return_value);
```