# Using PHP's exec() function (or the likes), how can you display terminal error output?

Tags: php, compiler-errors, terminal, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know the error in command in an exec function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148291/how-can-i-know-the-error-in-command-in-an-exec-function)

I am just wondering if there's a way (using PHP) to output the compile error information from the terminal to the browser?

For example:
If you use this code to execute in the terminal...

`gcc -o try try.c`

...and assuming the "try.c" have some errors.
The terminal will output something like this:

- try.c In function 'main':
- try.c:27 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
- try.c:27 (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
- try.c:27 for each function it appears in.)

Meanwhile, using this PHP code...

`<?php
exec("gcc -o try try.c");
?>`

The browser does not return any output like the terminal does. Is there a possible way direct or indirect that the error details that the terminal showed can be passed to the be displayed on a browser?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is STDOUT and STDERR. The output you describe is most likely on STDERR. Catch STDERR and return it.

Comment: @hakre duplicate of duplicate

Comment: Use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to get a pipe for STDERR.

Answer (score 0):

As @hakre has noted in the comments - you can simply redirect the STDERR stream, but here's another solution:

```
exec('command here', $output, $exit_status);
if ($exit_status !== 0) echo implode('<br />', $output);
```

If execution was successful - each program should return an exit status of 0 and any other code should mean some kind of an error.