# PHP passthru() returning "sh: 1: svn: not found " error

Tags: php, linux, svn, exec, server

Our university has free hosting on a Linux server, in which I have checked out a SVN project into my local student directory.  While remotely logging into the server, I have no problems adding/committing/etc to my SVN project sandbox on the server.

I have a PHP script on the same server that makes a [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) call to perform a simple SVN version number command on that sandbox:

```
<?php
    echo passthru(' 2>&1 cd /nav/to/svnSandbox && 2>&1 svn --version ');
?>
```

The above exec() call fails server-side and outputs

"sh: 1: svn: not found" to the [client](http://www.cs.uky.edu/~mtlank2/499sholem/stub499.php) side.  This implies that SVN isn't installed?  However, it is in fact installed on the server, moreover I can use SVN just fine while I'm logged in.

The following PHP code works correctly:

```
<?php
    echo passthru('pwd');
?>
```

User permissions for the PHP script and the SVN sandbox directory are 755 (I've tried many other variations as well).  I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143006/php-execsvn-commit-is-not-returning-any-errors-nor-working) link, among many others.

Is a PHP script not granted certain access to server-side SVN commands?

Why can't I make successful SVN exec() calls from my script? Is there an easier way than my code above?

Do server-admins usually have some sort of safeguard on scripts using exec() that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

> This implies that SVN isn't installed?

No, it simply implies that `svn` cannot be found in your path.

That *may* be because it's not installed or it may be that your path simply isn't set up correctly for the method you're using.

Compare the output of:

```
<?php
    echo passthru('echo $PATH');
?>
```

and executing `echo $PATH` when logged in to the box.

You'll probably find the `svn` directory on the latter but not the former.

Then it'll be a matter of figuring out how to set the path for the passthru method.

That *may* be as simple as something like:

```
<?php
    echo passthru('( cd /nav/to/svnSandbox; PATH=$PATH:/svnpath; svn --version ) 2>&1');
?>
```

or:

```
<?php
    echo passthru('( cd /nav/to/svnSandbox; /svnpath/svn --version ) 2>&1');
?>
```

Comment: You were right about the differences in PATH.  Thank you, I have learned a lot.  Unfortunately the only thing in the PHP script's PATH is /bin, and I'm not sure I can set the PATH variable through the exec call with what's in there.

Comment: Young @Padawan, set it you can :-) That command you're giving looks like a general shell command, so modifying `PATH` should work just fine. Or you could just try running the absolute path of `svn`, as shown in the update (replacing `/svnpath` with the _actual_ path to `svn` of course).